# Can't resolve dependencies: 'Bundler could not find compatible versions...'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Trying to upgrade Rails, set version to '5.0.0' in Gemfile. I don't understand why for example **actionpack** is not resolved after `bundle update`:

```
Resolving dependencies..............................................................
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
In Gemfile:
apivore was resolved to 1.6.2, which depends on
  actionpack (< 6, >= 4)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.0.0)

responders (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
  actionpack (< 5.3, >= 4.2.0)

rspec-rails was resolved to 3.7.2, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
```

As far as I understand this should has been resolved to **5.0.0** Did I miss something?

Comment: try bundle update

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

1. Run "bundle update" instead of "bundle install" and paste in the full output here
2. Go through the steps outlined here: http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html to see if that helps

Comment: yeah, I've used bundle update before getting this output, sorry had to mentioned this in the question